# Sum of sequence of random variables infinitely often positive

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be an infinite sequence of independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) random variables with $E(X_i)=0$ for all $i$.  Set $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. I want to show that for *any* such sequence

$\Pr (S_n\geq 0 \; \mbox{  i.o. (  infinitely often}))>0$

Any ideas? relevant references?  If necessary, additional assumptions on the variance may be added, e.g. that there is a bound $B$ such that $Var(X_i)\leq B$.

Thanks

Comment: With no uniform bound on the variance there are simple counterexamples.

Comment: What is a counter example with no such bound?

Comment: A classical one is when $P(X_i=-1)=i^2/(1+i^2)$, $P(X_i=i^2)=1/(1+i^2)$, then $X_i=-1$ for every $i$ large enough, almost surely, hence $S_n\to-\infty$ when $n\to\infty$, almost surely.

Comment: @Did Thanks.  That clarifies it.